# Is there a way to find out how long it takes for websphere process a request

Tags: websphere, websphere-6.1

I have an issue where I need to monitor how long it takes for Websphere to process a request.  Specifically I need to know how much time is spent in the "application world", that is time spent processing code in the ear file.

I can't just compute request_time - reponse_time because that contains time spent in the container or what I call "websphere world".  I need to know the time spent only in the ear file.

Is there some performance setting I can toggle in websphere so this information gets logged to the server system log file?  The application does not have log4j.

I am using Websphere 6.1

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the PMI interface under the WAS admin console.  It provides some performance metrics -- not the prettiest or easiest interface, but it might provide what you're looking for.

A monitoring plugin is often used to do this.  My company uses Introscope via a WAS JBM plugin, and it provides a better interface than PMI for viewing the performance data.  Of course, it isn't free, but there may be free or cheap alternatives that are better than PMI.

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere has something called "request metrics"

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/tprf_rqenable.html

It gives you the possibility to log braked down request execution times on different levels. As you may expect with such monitoring it's easy to collect to much data so there is a possibility to filter events based on additional criteria like java package namespace, EJB name, URI etc.